# How can I display a specific text related to a specific date using date picker?

Tags: ios, datepicker

I'm new to iOS and I'm not familiar with all its APIs. I found out how to display the selected date in a textfield, but I don't know what to write to display a specific (chosen) text related to a specific date.

This is the codes I have used to display the date. Do you know what I need to change to be able to write my own texts to specific dates?:

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @implementation ViewController
 @synthesize datePicker;
 @synthesize dateLabel;

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
 }

 #pragma mark - View lifecycle

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }

 - (void)viewDidUnload
 {
     [self setDateLabel:nil];
     [self setDatePicker:nil];
     [super viewDidUnload];
     // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
     // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
 }

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 }

 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 }

 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }

 - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
 }

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
     // Return YES for supported orientations
     return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
 }

 - (IBAction)touchButton:(id)sender {

     NSDate *dateSelect = [datePicker date];
     NSString *dateStamp = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"The date is %@", dateSelect];

     dateLabel.text = dateStamp;
 }
 @end
```

(I have a button, the date picker and a text field)

I would really appreciate your answers.

Comment: you bind  and  set the delegate of date picker ?

Comment: Is your question really about how to format the output of the date value?

Comment: No, I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear. I would like to have one text for each day of the year, like a daily quote.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use formatters. Take a look...

```
...
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]; <--- This will show hours and minutes
NSString *dateStamp = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
...
```

In setDateFormat you are allowed to set the output format you desire in this way...

dd - day
MM - month
yyyy - year
HH - hour
mm - minute
ss - second

... so [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy, HH:mm"] will get you something like "01/01/2013, 13:45".

Comment: It's not a good idea to hard code the date format. It is much better to set the date formatter's `dateStyle`. This way the date or time is formatted properly based on the user's locale.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, this is not best way for screen diplay but perfect for exact format dates (example: dates to sent to a server that not accept timestamps). He asked for "be able to write my own texts to specific dates".

Comment: The posted code shows the date being displayed in a label. Labels are shown to the user. Therefore they should be formatted properly based on the user's locale, not a specific format. This is a suggestion to the OP more than to you.